# The default asset for gscatter in blender does not appear

Tags: add-on

I'm looking to use Gscatter addon as a blender. I'm trying to install and use Addon, but none of the default assets appear in the Gscatter asset browser. There is only asset available for free download on the Graswald site.
When I watch YouTube videos, the default asset appears in the Asset Browser, how can it look? I don't see it! I'll be waiting for your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Since that seems to be a third-party addon and not part of Blender you'll have to ask the addon author that question.

Comment: You have to add the path of the assets in *Edit > Preferences > File Paths > Asset Libraries*